# PHP MySQL Search with string & location distance

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `user` with with columns `latitude` and `longitude`.

Another table `products` with  columns `title` `description`

I am trying to create a PHP search form where the results are filtered by the keywords/string input and location input.

So essentially, I'm trying to query the products table to find matches, while querying the users table for proximity. You search for a product, and the result shows the stores that has the products nearest to you.

This is the query I have for matching keywords/strings

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(item_name,item_desc) AGAINST(:searchstr IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND public = 1`

I was trying to using foreign keys/referencing the lat/lng column in `user` table in `products` table but I had no luck.

```
"SELECT *,
        truncate((degrees(acos(
        sin(radians(lat))
        * sin( radians(:lat))
        + cos(radians(lat))
        * cos( radians(:lat))
        * cos( radians(lng - :lng) ) 
        ) ) * 69.09),1) as distance FROM users, product 
WHERE MATCH(product.item_name,product.item_desc) AGAINST(:searchstr IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND public = 1";
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks

Edit: I'm already using a foreign key to connect each product with specific users (user.id = products.user_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you need to JOIN the two tables together.  Try this:

```
"SELECT *,
    truncate((degrees(acos(
    sin(radians(lat))
    * sin( radians(:lat))
    + cos(radians(lat))
    * cos( radians(:lat))
    * cos( radians(lng - :lng) ) 
    ) ) * 69.09),1) as distance FROM users
JOIN product ON product.user_id = users.id
WHERE MATCH(product.item_name,product.item_desc) AGAINST(:searchstr IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND public = 1
ORDER BY distance";
```

Also, make sure you have the correct table names.  In your question you say "user" and "products", but in your query you have "users" and "product".